# Use Duetds Datepicker with Wicket?

Tags: datepicker, wicket

The Duetds Datepicker (https://github.com/duetds/date-picker) is an accessible Datepicker which i would like to use, however the usage is as follows:

```
<duet-date-picker identifier="date"></duet-date-picker>
```

which is incompatible with Wicket Form Components which require **input** HTML-Tags.

Do you know of a method to use this Datepicker with Wicket or another accessible Datepicker that can be used with Wicket? (Jquery UI Datepicker is not good as is closes on Tab)

Comment: `FormComponentPanel` doesn't need a input tag and you can provide your own markup just like in a normal panel. So my idea would be to add `duet-date-picker` inside the panel and give it a `name` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use this JS widget with Wicket!

In your Java code do:

```
WebComponent datePicker = new WebComponent("datePicker");
parent.add(datePicker);
datePicker.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("duetChange") {
   @Override public void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
      long timestamp = getRequest().getParametersValue("selectedDate").toLong();
      // use timestamp here
   }

   @Override public void updateAjaxRequestAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attrs) {
      super.updateAjaxRequestAttributes(attrs);

      attrs.getDynamicExtraParameters().add("return {\"name\": \"selectedDate\", \"value\": attrs.e.detail.valueAsDate.getTime()}");
   }
});
```

The HTML would be like:

```
 <duet-date-picker wicket:id="datePicker" identifier="date"></duet-date-picker>
```

Comment: Yes but its not the same as just submitting a form with inputs

Comment: For form submit you can do the same by listening on form's `submit` JavaScript event. Instead of using WebComponent you should create a custom FormComponent that stores/provides the date value.